# Amending timestamps using powershell or creating files in specified order from a csv

Tags: powershell, csv, timestamp

I have n number of files that have been created from a csv list by copying an original file using PowerShell:

```
Import-Csv C:\TEST\test.csv | % { Copy-Item -Path $_.oldfilepath –Destination "C:\TEST\$($_.newfilename)”}
```

Where .oldfile path is the original file and .newfilename is in the format xxxxx02012014.filetype

This takes the original file and creates as many copies as required using the names within the csv.  However in doing so I lose the original/expected order of the files when viewing in explorer as they all appear to have been created at the same time (They are actually in ascending date order of the format of xxxxx02012014, xxxxx02082014 etc. where the number is a week in american date format).

Because of the required naming convention I cannot sort on name and due to how the files are produced (at the same timestamp) I cannot sort of time created within windows.

Is there either a way to ensure the files created and listed in the same order or something else I can run in PowerShell on the subsequently created files to modify the timestamps so they appear in windows explorer in the order required i.e in ascending american date format.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the creation time of the copy with the creation timestamp from the original:

```
Import-Csv C:\TEST\test.csv | % {
  $target = "C:\TEST\$($_.newfilename)"
  Copy-Item -Path $_.oldfilepath –Destination $target
  (Get-Item $target).CreationTime = (Get-Item $_.oldfilepath).CreationTime
}
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your response. Just to clarify, there is a list of say 1000 filenames in the csv (.newfilepath) but they are all just duplicating the exact same original file (.oldfilepath) but giving it a new name to end up with 1000 new files of a certain type, but with unique names.  So this method won't work unfortunately as it would give the same creationtime for all. I was wondering if I could put a column in the csv with a nominal different creationtime for all for this to be taken instead?

Comment: @MikeyD: You didn't explain in your question where the creation date is supposed to come from, so I assumed you wanted to keep the date of the original file. Of course it's possible to apply a date from another column in the CSV. It's also possible to derive the date from the file name, if that's what you want.